# scipy nquad with arguments

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I have the following code

```
def f(x, y, ro):
    return x*y*ro

def bounds_y():
    return [0, 0.5]

def bounds_x(y):
    return [0, 1-2*y]

scipy.integrate.nquad(f, [bounds_x, bounds_y, [0.5] ], args= [0.5])
```

Without the args, the code works. But when I add the args, I am getting the following error

```
bounds_y() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Why this is the case and how to resolve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Reread what `nquad` says about callable `ranges` parameters, in particular what arguments they should take.  `args` is passed to them!

Comment: scipy.integrate.nquad(f, [bounds_x, bounds_y()] ], args= [0.5]) works. Thanks.